# Memory alignment and long copies

Tags: c++, c, memory, alignment

If we assume that i align a block of memory with memalign to 4bytes , would it still be safe to do :

```
unsigned int* source = In.Data;
unsigned int* dest = Out.Data;

int loops = In.Size / 4; //size is the same for both in/out 

while (loops)
{
    *dest++=*source++;
    loops--;
}
```

Instead copying 1byte at a time? If not how to tell if the memory is properly aligned in order to fallback to standard byte copies if needed?

Comment: You have to align the memory to `alignof(unsigned int)`, not "4 bytes".

Comment: Yes i do that (sizeof(unsigned int)) D:

Comment: It is not generally required that `alignof(T) == sizeof(T)`, though. For instance, consider the `long double` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe as your blocks are properly aligned.

It would also be safe if get your blocks from `malloc` as the block of memory returned by `malloc` is guaranteed to be properly aligned for any purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply :D